# Auto complete select function not working using jquery ui?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Everything seems to work except when I add the following lines in the autocomplete select function:

```
           select: function(event)
                   {
                       BK.searchIndex = $.inArray(ui.item.value, BK.arrayList);
                       alert(BK.searchIndex);
                   });
```

In firebug, I see the following error message:

```
            ReferenceError: ui is not defined
            BK.searchIndex = $.inArray(ui.item.value, BK.arrayList);
```

If I comment out code in select, everything works. Any idea what could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be this:

```
select: function(event,ui){...}
```

Comment: Stackoverflow makes me wait 10 minutes before accepting an answer